# How to convert string of the form '1,1' into float (1,1)?

Tags: python, sorting, scripting, type-conversion

I have a file containing multiple lines of the form:

```
'1  2.45       3455                 3,5'
'36 1.055   2290                   1,6'
...........
...........
```

I was able to strip off the spaces and make a list of lists like this:

```
[ ['1','2.45','3455','3,5'], ['36','1.055','2290','1,6'],[......]...]
```

I need to sort this list by the last element of each list. This requires that I convert the last element from string to float/int so that I can supply this as a key to the 'sorted' function. The result should look as follows:

```
[  ['36','1.055','2290','1,6'], ['1','2.45','3455','3,5'],[......]...]
```

Could you please let me know how to do this kind of conversion?

Comment: Why does the data have mixed radix points?

Comment: The last element are actually co-ordinates. They are actually (1,6) , (3,5) and so on.

Comment: How would you like to order them then?

Comment: In increasing order. Eg: (1,1), (1,2), (2.3), (3,5), (5,8), (10, 67), (67,45) etc

Comment: How would you order (1, 11), (2, 1), and (1, 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *str.replace*, replacing the comma with a period using a lambda as the sort key casting the replaced str to float:

```
l = [ ['1','2.45','3455','3,5'], ['36','1.055','2290','1,6'],['36','1.055','2290','11,6']]


print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: float(x[-1].replace(",","."))))
```

Which will sort by the last element, comparing as floats not strings:

```
 [['36', '1.055', '2290', '1,6'], ['1', '2.45', '3455', '3,5'], ['36', '1.055', '2290', '11,6']]
```

Comment: That was a bloody brilliant idea! Many thanks, Mr.Cunningham. May I ask where did you develop such chops from? A book, or, some source on the web. What would be a helpful source for a beginner?

Comment: @anirudh1624, no worries, I think this is a very good resource http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Comment: Thanks @Padraic Cunningham!

Answer (score 0):

> This requires that I convert the last element from string to float/int so that I can supply this as a key to the 'sorted' function.

Incorrect. The `key` argument can return *any* object, including sequences, provided that they are orderable. And since sequences sort naively:

```
..., key=lambda x: x[-1].split(','), ...)
```